# While loop - possible to have only 6 loops?

Tags: php, while-loop

This is my code, I would like it so that it only does the first 6 array items. Also, how would I write a loop for everything AFTER the 6 first array items?

```
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray")) {

    ECHO "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
}
```

Comment: Can you give your query as well?

Comment: On a different note, notice that you are concatenating the array `$servdescarrayrow` as a string and are passing `mysql_fetch_array()` a string instead of a resource. I guess that's edited out for simplification here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following for your first request:

```
$count = 0;
while($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray")) {
  $count++;
  echo "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
  if($count == 6){
    break;
  }
}
```

Then you could do the below for part 2:

```
$count = 0;
while($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray")) {
  $count++;
  if($count > 6){
    echo "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
  }
}
```

Alternatively (and better) is to use `LIMIT` in your SQL query

Comment: Don't think you need a string for this... What's wrong with numbers?

Comment: My bad... one of those days :(

Answer (score 4):

To have just the first 6 rows, the best way is to use [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) in your sql statement in this way.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition
LIMIT 6
```

If you want to have a loop that print the first 6 rows and then another loop that will print the remaining rows use the solution provided by [nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862594/nickb).

Answer (score 2):

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray");
    ECHO "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
}
```

To get the remaining entries (since the result set will remember where it left off):

```
while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray")) {

    ECHO "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE condition 
OFFSET 6
```

this query will get everything after the first 6.
I'm assuming you're using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a single loop approach. To keep it simple and readable, us a count variable `$rowNum` to determine what to do in your loop.

```
    $rowNum = 0;
    while ($servdescarrayrow = mysql_fetch_array("servdescarray")) {
        $rowNum++;

        if($rowNum<=6)
        {
             ECHO "<fieldset>Services: ".$servdescarrayrow."</fieldset>";
        }
        else
        {
            // Code for other items
        }
    }
```